# Webpack configuration not loading my image paths on .ts files

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

I'm very new with webpack, and actually this whole modern front-end development. I'm trying to learn angular2 this past few weeks, it was fine until I wanted to deploy it. I came across webpack that produces the index.html with all the angular2 thingy packed on a script, so I could deploy the website I am experimenting.

The problem is when the paths of my images doesn't seem to be processed by webpack. Html and css were fine, but when I try do something like:

```
import {ImageSection} from './image-section';

export const PAGEONE: ImageSection = {
    title: "Page One",
    imgsrc: "../../../public/images/pageone.png"
}
```

Here's my webpack configuration:

### webpack.common.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'app': './src/main.ts'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js']
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      { 
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
        loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap')
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: 'raw'
      },
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

Should I add some loader on the .ts one? I'm just really trying to learn angular, forgive my noobness on webpack. I just really want to make it work, study angular first to at least a comfortable degree and then start learning this webpack thing.

Comment: please check your image path, is that correct?

Comment: yes, because it works when I use the same path, directly on the html. It just doesn't work on .ts. I am forced to code the similar components, instead of just defining one template and just binding the data on it while doing a forloop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

webpack cannot guess from arbitrary JavaScript strings, whether the string needs to be loaded. You need to `require` the resource. In your example, replace

`imgsrc: "../../../public/images/pageone.png"`

with

`imgsrc: require("../../../public/images/pageone.png")`

This emits `pageone.png` as file in the output directory and returns the public URL. For details see the [usage section of the `file-loader`](https://github.com/webpack/file-loader#usage).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm. I just really want webpack to get out of the way while getting the ropes around angular2, this really helped a lot. I can focus on the task at hand now. Thank you very much!